# How do you strip an EQUALS SYMBOL from a string that a user inputs into a windows batch file CLI?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to get a batch file to allow a user to input the string "blahblahblah=12345" and then STRIP the first 13 characters of the string, including the equals sign. The problem is
every time I try to enter the = (equals sign) i get this "= was unexpected at this time" error.

Here is the batch script:

```
REM BEGIN

@echo off

set /p STUFF="type in something: "

IF %STUFF%==blahblahblah^= goto 2 

:2

 set STUFF=%STUFF:~13%

 echo %STUFF%

REM END
```

Ok, now what i want actually works as long as I DO NOT INPUT AN = (EQUALS SIGN)

So if it the input was `blahblahblah12345`
The output is: `12345`

However, if I input the `blahblahblah=12345`
then the output is

```
=12345==blahblahblah= was unexpected this time.
```

I've tried doing the `FOR /f "delims== tokens=1"` stuff, but I can't figure out how to make that work for what I'm trying to do. It's pretty specific, I want to just remove the equals sign as well as the "blahblahblah" from the "12345" so the output is just "12345". Can anyone help?

Comment: My suggestion is not to enter a **`=`** from the outset! What's the harm in asking for string/sum/variable then asking for value? `Set /P "variable=enter variable name: "` followed by `Set /P "value=enter value for %variable%: "`

Answer (score 0):

Use quotation marks:

```
IF "%STUFF%"=="blahblahblah=" goto 2
```

Batch expands variables before processing commands, so, without quotes batch would interpret something  like `IF blahblahblah=12345==blahblahblah goto 2` causing `IF` to fail.

Comment: omfg. Thank you so much I couldn't find anything on quotations. It worked!

Comment: btw, could you explain why you need to use quotes around %STUFF% ? I figured it would just work with the quotations for "blahblahblah=" but apparently that is not the case, as I've tried that and it did not work. But your example DID, i just don't understand why you'd have to put quotes around the variable?

Comment: @TomcatCruiser, the comparison is a LITERAL string comparison. Plain and simple. Qutoes are always used in batch files to protect spaces and special characters. My best practice is to always use them.